# Two different inputs merged based on positions

Tags: java

I want to merge two strings in Java, for example inputs are hello and world, then output should be hweolrldo?

How to merge them after reading the inputs from user and merging them to give an output as in example.

Comment: `System.out.println(IntStream.range(0, str1.length()).mapToObj(i -> str1.charAt(i) + "" + str2.charAt(i)).collect(Collectors.joining()))`

Comment: @shmosel:
If you want to answer the question use the answer function please.

Comment: @FabianSchöner Ah, but I don't.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, nor do I know of anyway to conveniently add the two words together. The first method I think of adding the two strings is by using substring, but it would be a tedious process. If you have the words as str1 and str2:

```
    private String str1 = "hello";
    private String str2 = "world";
```

You can get add the two by gathering the substring of each letter. (Remember that when using substring, the numbering is that of the index numbers of each character of the string, so in str1, h=0, e=1, l=2, and so on.)

You can combine the two like this:

```
String combined = str1.substring(0,1) + str2.substring(0,1) + str1.substring(1,2) + str2.substring(1,2) + str1.substring(2,3) + str2.substring(2,3) + str1.substring(3,4) + str2.substring(3,4) + str1.substring(4,5) + str2.substring(4,5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help you.!

```
    String firstWord="hello";
    String secondWord="World";
    String combineString=" ";

    for(int i=0;i<firstWord.size();i++)
    {

       combineString+=firstWord.charAt(i)+secondWord.charat(i);
    }
```